# How to create a drop down list with php from an sql table AND display a dynamic default form value in the drop down list

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

I am creating a form for a user to change demographics about a member.  I want to provide a drop down list in an HTML form with PHP AND display a default value based on a value from a table.

Example:  Change a member's zipcode based on a dropdown list of zipcodes we serve (no text input just select from a list) AND display the member's current zipcode assignment by default.

```
<form>

<?php 
  // NOTE - geo meeting is equivalent to zipcodes
   $geo_locations = '<select name="geo1" id="geo1"> <option selected value="BAL"> Select new Location</option>';
     WHILE($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($geomeetings))
                {
         $geo_locations .= ' <option value="'.$row['geo1'].'">'.$row['geoloc'].'</option>';
                }
         $geo_locations .= '</select>';
              echo '<TD>'.$geo_locations.'</TD>';
  // End of dropdown list of geo meeting locations -
?>
```

Comment: and what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Please see answer posted below. If this answers your question, please click the checkbox at left of the answer to mark it as correct and close the question.

Comment: Hi - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below one of the answers, or edit your question to clarify what else you need help with. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer. You won't get any points for doing so, but that will close out the question. *Thanks!*

Comment: Hey TW - following up again. Could we trouble you to either select a best answer, or provide one, to close out the question? That would help us out. *Many Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

So, you have the $geomeetings table, which contains ALL the zipcodes. You also have another table - the user table - that has the zipcode for that user.

***Off-the-cuff and untested, but you get the idea...***

```
<?php 
    // NOTE - geo meeting is equivalent to zipcodes
    $user_geo_loc = '12345'; //This value comes from the user table
    $geo_locations = '
        <select name="geo1" id="geo1">
            <option value=""> Select new Location</option>
    ';
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($geomeetings) ){
        $issel = '';
        if ($user_geo_loc == $row['geoloc']) $issel = ' selected';
        $geo_locations .= ' <option value="'.$row['geo1'].'" ' .$issel. '>'.$row['geoloc'].'</option>';
    }
    $geo_locations .= '</select>';
  // End of dropdown list of geo meeting locations -
?>

<form>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Location: <?php echo $geo_locations; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

---

Note that this structure can also be replaced with a TERNARY operator, which would look like this:

```
$issel = ($user_geo_loc == $row['geoloc']) ? ' selected' : '';
```

*(That would read, `IF $user_geo == $row_geo THEN $issel = 'selected' ELSE $issel = ''` )*

Comment: I am trying to provide a dropdown list with one of those elements displayed by default based on the member's current assignment. <option selected value="BAL">  I tried to replace "BAL" with a variable populate from a table but, doesn't seem to work. -

Comment: Answer updated to address this. Basically, for each `<option>` row in the while loop, you test if the value of that $geo option is equal to the $geo value you stored in the user table for that user's zipcode.

Comment: From your description above (better than my description) you get the idea.  Unfortunately, I can not test this at this time.  Will do later.  Just wanted to reply and say thanks! This may do it, (if so I will respond in the Answer Your Question button).

Comment: Again thanks for the help.  Unfortunately this does not provide the dropdown list.  Perhaps I don't understand completely.  However, I do like the Ternary option.  Nice clean code. I have inserted into the file, but commented it out for now.  I'll add a second comment next.

Comment: I am trying to assign a variable to XXX (below) as the member's current location. But I keep getting a "T-VARIABLE" error.  Apparently I can not assign a variable.  $geo_locations = ' <option selected value="XXX"> Select new Location</option>';Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$mbr_geo1' (T_VARIABLE) in